# How can I integrate the pod into projectname.xcworkscape?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Normally we integrate a pod into the xcodeproj file and after integration .xcworkspace is created. But I already have **projectName.xcworkspace** in my project.
How can I integrate the pod file into the projectName.xcworkspace file in my project?

This is the structure of my project:

```
porjectName:
 -projectName
 -projectName.xcodeproj
projectName.xcworkspace
projectNameApi:
 -projectNameApi
 -projectNameApi.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still integrate them as you did for your xcodeproj, edit your podfile, save it, go back to your terminal and write pod install.

Actually, whenever you have to integrate pods somewhere, open your terminal, write `cd` drag the folder containing your project in your terminal and press return so that you'll be in the right directory. Then write pod init and open the pod file, you write the pod names then save. You return to your terminal and write pod install. All done.

Comment: I've not integrated the pod before in this file. I manually created the .xcworkspace file. so there is no podfile.

Comment: Ok try doing what I explained in the second part of my answer

Comment: That way you'll create the podfile